# How to add a marker in google maps when the object is moving is React

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm building React app with API that tracks some objects and I don't use any lib to manage the google maps. When I'm setting a static LatLng it shows where it should be, but when it gets data which is updated every second it's not showing.
can you help me?

```
class GoogleMap extends Component {

    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps( nextProps ) {
        this.map.panTo({lat: nextProps.lat, lng: nextProps.lng})
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // this.myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        this.position = {
            center: {
                lat: this.props.lat,
                lng: this.props.lng
            }
        };
        this.mapOptions = {
            center: this.position,
            zoom: 5,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        };
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, this.mapOptions);
        this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: this.myLatLng,
            map: this.map
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="map" ref="map"/>
        );
    }
}
export default GoogleMap;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To update marker position you could utilize [`setPosition` function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) of `Marker` class instead of [`mapTo` function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) which *changes the center of the map to the given lat/lng*

2)There is a typo in initializing `position`, the expected format for `center` property of [`MapOptions` object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions) is as follows:

```
this.position = {
   lat: this.props.lat,
   lng: this.props.lng
};
```

The following example demonstrates how to move a marker in React:

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/9nu4tpba/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use marker.setPosition to update the position of a marker, It takes a
LatLng as an argument and moves the marker there.

Here is a reference to the Google Maps Javascript API for marker.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Marker